# Breaking open WordPress into PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm interested in taking a WordPress site, complete with its plugins and theme, and breaking all the code out into a unified, purpose-built system where all modules become an integral part of the code base. I have two questions:

1) Is this practical?

2) What's the best way to approach it?

Comment: .....why? What's up with standard wordpress?

Comment: 'What's up with standard wordpress' - WP is inefficient, prone to attacks and is a general purpose tool not fitting exactly for custom use cases. If i ever try that, i will begin by taking a copy of wordpress database onto my localhost and use a framework like YII to generate auto model codes for wp database schema. When I am done with core functionality will i bother about porting plugin related functionality

Comment: No general purpose tool is "fitting exactly for custom use cases". You have to understand the strengths and weaknesses of the framework and work within it. If it doesn't do what you want, use something else; or, adapt to the framework. WP can be efficient, and while subject to attacks, there are steps you can take to overcome this. You just have to be smart about how you approach the issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, this isn't practical.
2. You don't. You work within the framework that already exists. Everything you are talking about essentially exists already.